# Label original and duplicate copies of report

Tags: crystal-reports

My report has 2 pages in one invoice. I need 3 copies for each invoice.
I want each to be labelled `1st copy - original copy`; `2nd copy- duplicate copy`; and `3rd copy - triplicate copy`.

How can I set this up?

Comment: use subreport for duplicate and triplicate

Comment: can you suggest me how?

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert subreport
2. In the selection window, choose *existing report*. Browse to your invoice report
3. In *Link Tab*, link your main report parameter to sub report parameter.
4. Then in the subreport, change the header duplicate.
5. Repeat steps for triplicate