# How to create 2 copies of crystal report with the only difference of a text which could be "Original" and "Duplicate"?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I am writing a WinForm application and have used Crystal Report to generate the billing invoice. As needed, I am able to create a report which has a Detail section to show the list of items and a Sub-report in the Page footer section to show summary of items.

Later I realised to get a duplicate copy of invoice, but I am not sure which direction to go. I tried with adding a New Detail Section (Details b) and pasted the fields from the (Details a).

Now, If I am adding 2 products then total pages getting generated are 3.

First page contains Item 1 in Details section.
Second page contains Item 1 and Item 2 (both) in Details section.
Third page contains Item 2 in Details section.

What all I want is just 2 copies with the same list and sub-report section and a text in the header of each page with a text signifying copy as Original and Duplicate.

I am newbie to Crystal Report so please let me know if question needs more clarity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921076/label-original-and-duplicate-copies-of-report?noredirect=1#comment76824087_44921076

Comment: Hi @Mahendra I'll try it. In case I would be having any issues, will you be able to check my code? It's a simple application for learning purpose.

Comment: Ok.You just need to change the report design.